# Run JavaScript Script snippet automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, code-snippets, business-objects

I want to run a script snippet on the SAP BO "Query Builder", it's a simple tool to retrieve data using SQL. (I can't upload the image due to the reputation, the product's interface can be found here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-42952)

Since I have a bunch of queries to run, I want to use snippet to run them automatically. Using the following code:

```
    //select the textarea to insert retrieved queries
    document.querySelector("textarea").textContent = "SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS";
    //click the submit button
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();

    //code to export the query result

    //after click(), the page reloaded and it won't executed the following code.
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    //back to the previous page, run the previous code again
        window.history.back(1);
        }, false);
```

Does anyone have good ideas how to implement it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for chrome and you can learn how to use it from sites like [hibbard tampermonkey tutorial](http://hibbard.eu/tampermonkey-tutorial/) .
Overall your sript would look like this:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Enter any name you like here
// @namespace    URL of website you own 
// @version      0.1
// @description  retrive data using sql
// @author       Your name here
// @match        relevant url
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */


// Your code here...
//select the textarea to insert retrieved queries
    document.querySelector("textarea").textContent = "SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS";
    //click the submit button
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();

    //code to export the query result

    //after click(), the page reloaded and it won't executed the following code.
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    //back to the previous page, run the previous code again
        window.history.back(1);
        }, false);
```

Make neccesay changes like in @match.
Please Comment if you have any doubts . hope it helps